# VisualVM and YourKit report different retained sizes for the same object

Tags: java, memory, visualvm, yourkit

I'm using JVisualVM and YourKit to analyze a heap memory dump (created using jmap) and noticed that for the same object they report two very different retained sizes! Does anybody know what the cause could be?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the obvious cause for this difference is a bug in VisualVM or YourKit. Can you try VisualVM 1.3.3 from http://visualvm.java.net ? If can you send me (privately) the link to your heap dump, I can investigate VisualVM part.

Comment: Sure, I'll try VisualVM 1.3.3

Comment: Got the same result using VisualVM 1.3.3. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share the heap dump!

Comment: Too bad you are to able to share the heap dump. In that case I am sorry, but I cannot help you. :-(